# Using clang libtooling to rewrite C++ source code to include implicitly defined constructors, operators and destructors

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, libtooling

According to the C++ standard:

> [Note:In some circumstances, C++implementations implicitly define the default constructor (12.1), copyconstructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment opera-tor (12.8), or destructor (12.4) member functions.— end note] [Example:given

```
#include <string>
struct C {
    std::string s;//std::stringis the standard library class (Clause 21)
};
int main() {
    C a;
    C b = a;
    b = a;
}
```

> the implementation will implicitly define functions to make the definition of C equivalent to

```
struct C {
    std::string s;
    C() : s() { }
    C(const C& x): s(x.s) { }
    C(C&& x): s(static_cast<std::string&&>(x.s)) { }
        //:  s(std::move(x.s)) { }
    C& operator=(const C& x) { s = x.s; return *this; }
    C& operator=(C&& x) { s = static_cast<std::string&&>(x.s); return *this; }
        //{ s = std::move(x.s); return *this; }~C() { }
};
```

My question is, is there a clang tool already in existence that will rewrite a C++ source and define all constructors/operators/destructors that would usually be generated implicitly at compile time.

I have a large source base, and wish to track object addresses (within a larger project). So I need a tool that will generate copy constructors for all my classes, which are identical to what the compiler would generate as default, but then I want to insert my own tracking style functions afterwards.

Many Thanks

Comment: You'd probably have better luck asking on the clang/llvm mailing lists about whether this tooling exists.